# Download CSV file get link

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on a code and I am stuck at a point which is how to get the URL of CSV file that I need to download
Here's the link as an example:
https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/obbligazioni/titoli-di-stato/btp/obbligazione/IT0004594930.MOT?refresh_ce
On the top right of the map there is element that enables to export to 3 extensions. I would like to get the link to the CSV file. I have tried to locate the element but I am confused and can't find a clue.

when I tried to get the link I got `https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/obbligazioni/titoli-di-stato/btp/obbligazione/IT0004594930.MOT?refresh_ce#` and this is general and not specific as a link to the CSV file.

Comment: Please include your code. For that code, include the request url and the expected url to retrieve.

Comment: I have posted the URL and I have no full code as I just inspected the HTML page and couldn't find a clue for the CSV link. `https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/obbligazioni/titoli-di-stato/btp/obbligazione/IT0004594930.MOT?refresh_ce`

Comment: I think file is dynamically generated and exported through plugin behind paywall? See the js in the following: https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/static/js/amcharts/plugins/export/export.min.js?v=b903-origin/master-paywall-2689cd1 I don't think there is a client side url you can use.